# Mapbox data driven styling for paint with boolean

Tags: mapbox

I'm trying to dynamically set the fill colour for a GeoJSON layer based on its properties.
The properties for the feature would be:

```
properties: {
    color: 'cyan',
    colorSelected: 'magenta',
    selected: false,
}
```

For the mapbox paint attribute, I have:

```
paint: {
    "fill-color": [
        'case',
        ['==', ['get', 'selected'], ['get', 'colorSelected']],
        ['get', 'color'],
    ]
}
```

The idea being that if the "selected" property is true, get colourSelected = 'magenta', else the default of 'cyan'

This is not working, how can I do this boolean selection?

Answer (score 1):

This solution ended up resolving my problem:

```
    "fill-color": [
        'case',
        ['==', ['get', 'selected'], true],
        ['get', 'fillColorSelected'],
        ['get', 'fillColor'],
    ],
```